# How would I make wp-admin appear for my Wordpress project?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I have a Wordpress project that successfully appears on the browser, meaning, the actual website appears fine locally.

I've pulled down this project from GitHub.  How would I go about opening this project on the Wordpress dashboard so I can actually make changes on the theme?  I think my main issue's that I can't access `wp-admin` (`myurl.com/wp-admin`).  Anyone have any suggestions on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access myurl.com/wp-login.php